# how to replace image in php?

Tags: php

I used this code for replacing an image, but the image is not uploaded in upload folder, but the database is updated.  I need to replace the image.

```
<?php
require("header.php");

$patientid = $_POST['patientid'];
$pname = $_POST['pname'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

if(!$pname || !$address) {
    echo "<center>";
    echo "Fillup required fields<br><br>";
    echo "</center>";
}
else {
    $ran2 = $patientid;
    $new_name2 = $ran2."b";
    $new_file_name2 = $new_name2."."."jpg";
    $path = "./members/".$new_file_name2;

    $copied = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_name']['tmp_name'], $path);

    if ($copied) {
        $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE info_store 
        SET pname='$pname', fname='$fname', address='$address', image1='$new_file_name2'
        WHERE patientid='$patientid'");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "<center><h3>There are An Errors In Uploading!</h3></center>";
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

Please give me a solution.

Comment: Some problems: Failing to check if the upload succeeded. SQL injection holes. Assuming the DB query succeeded. Pointless string concatenation operations. Horrible form validation... Ouch.

Comment: do check your upload file size limit

Answer (score 2):

Look this( **to replace a picture** ):

**YOUR PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
$path = '/my/folder/uploads/';
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc("select source from images where id = X ");
$File_Name_Here  = $path . $row['source'];
@unlink( $path. $File_Name_Here );

$output = $path . 'md5(time()).jpg'

copy( $_FILE['image']['tmp_name'] , $output );
?>
```

Please, use function **copy** and read this documentation:

[PHP FUNCTION:COPY](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

[PHP FUNCTION:UNLINK](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

**YOUR HTML CODE:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...Your fields here...
</form>
```

On forms, defined as the attribute method "POST" and add the attribute "enctype"

**YOU PHP SQL CODE:**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE images SET source ='".mysql_real_escape_string( $output )."' WHERE id = X");
```

Please, use MYSQL_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING

[PHP FUNCTION:MYSQL_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

**YOU PHP.INI CODE**

```
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M
```

If needed, increase the limit in your php.ini, only if you are administrator.

Comment: boss in this delete is done but image is not copied.

    @<?php
 //$patientid=$_GET['patientid'];
    $dir = "./upload";
 $ran2= $patientid;
    $new_name2=$ran2."1";
    $file_name=$new_name2."."."jpg";
    $complete_path = $dir."/".$file_name;
 $fileName= time()."."."jpg";
 $path = $dir."/".$fileName;
 
    if(unlink($complete_path))
  {
  echo "Successfully deleted the file";
  } 
 else
  {
  echo"File not deleted";
  } 
 if(copy($_FILE['image1']['tmp_name'], $path))
  {
  echo "";
  }
 else
  {
  echo "Not Replaced";
  }

    ?>